# View partial over navigationBar (Feedly app like)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a UITableView that can be ordered with filters.
Instead of using a modal view i wanted to just make an animation of a view comming from the left of the screen and partially covering my tableView.

Here is an exemple of what i want my "filters view" to look like :

Without the filter :

[image: Without the filter]

With the filter :

[image: With the filter]

What could do the trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way, with reusable code:

add Animation category to `UIView`

```
@interface UIView (MyAnimation)
-(void)slideInWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

//implementation

-(void)slideInWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float nSpace = 0.0f //put any value you think right
    CGFloat extraOffset = self.view.frame.size.width / 2 + nSpace;

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(screenRect.origin.x - extraOffset, self.view.center.y)];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.view.center];
    animation.duration = duration;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SlideInAnimation"];
}
```

in `SomeWhereViewController.m`

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
someView.frame = // customize to your like
[mainWindow addSubview:someView];

[someView slideInWithDuration:0.7];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

One way is, Add this new view with frame set in such a way that view is outside the current view and then animate the frame using animation block to current position. You need to add this new view on `self.navigationController.view`.

For eg:-

```
newView.frame = frameOutsideCurrentView;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    delay:1.0
    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
    animations:^{
        newView.frame = currentFrame;
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){

    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the overlaying view in a `UIWindow` and set the `windowLevel` property to `UIWindowLevelAlert` or `UIWindowLevelStatusBar`.